# update sql statement where the value total of all column vaules

Tags: php, mysql

I have an number of different categories for my blog site posts; I also have an total number of total posts, how do I write an sql statement to update the entry in the total number of posts = to the number of the sum of my different categories?

here is what I have os far

```
$blog_number_update = "UPDATE `blog_categories` SET `posts_counter` = '(total of all other rows with an number greater then 0 in the posts_counter column)' WHERE `name` = 'Number'"
```

how to write this?

(total of all other rows with an number greater then 0 in the posts_counter column)

Answer (score 0):

You can combine these queries using a sub query.

Something like

```
 UPDATE `blog_categories` SET `posts_counter` =(SELECT SUM(posts_counter) FROM blog_categories WHERE posts_counter>0) WHERE `name` = `value`
```

should work fine. However, with large data sets, this could have some serious performance implications.

Comment: is this faster or slower then just using 2 sql queries?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea to store both the counters and their sum in the same table. It would be wiser to have a separate table for this kind of statistics (and only if calculating them on the fly is too slow).

Here's a way to bypass MySQL's limitation of not using the same table in a subquery in the `WHERE` clause when you `UPDATE` it:

```
UPDATE
        ( SELECT SUM(posts_counter) AS counter_sum
          FROM blog_categories 
          WHERE posts_counter > 0 
            AND ( name <> 'Number' OR name IS NULL ) 
        ) AS s 
    CROSS JOIN 
        blog_categories AS b
SET
    b.posts_counter = s.counter_sum
WHERE 
    b.name = 'Number' ;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't update a table, that you select from, in MySQL - so this is not possible in one query.

To do it in 2 parts, you could

```
SELECT SUM(posts_counter) FROM blog_categories WHERE posts_counter>0
```

(The `WHERE` clause is redundant, if you have no negative values there), get the results into the PHP variable `$posts_counter`, then run

```
UPDATE `blog_categories` SET `posts_counter` = $posts_counter WHERE `name` = 'Number'
```

Comment: WHile I don't have a problem with a -1, I am eager to learn: What's wrong in this answer? Or is it just, that I am the bearer of unwelcome news?